# What is the limit for number of subscribers to a stream(publisher's) in opentok/tokbox iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, iphone, opentok, tokbox

Hi iCoders currently i'm working on an app for live streaming using OpenTok/TokBox iOS SDK.My doubt is how many number of subscribers can subscribe to a stream published by a publisher.I have searched about this in openTok forums but no where found about this.If anyone know about this please share your answer.

Thanks,

ravi.

Comment: I know this is old...but did u find any limit for open tok in iOS

Comment: No, there is no limit at that time.

Comment: Im facing heating issue in my device when I use open tok with more than 5 streams. And someitmes it crashes with memory exception

Answer (score 4):

I believe there is no limitation in how many subscribers you have on a published stream. The only thing you need to consider is using `relayed` or `routed` sessions, [see doc](https://tokbox.com/developer/concepts/relayed-vs-routed/).

If you are using relayed sessions you are limited with the bandwidth on the device. And you will open a stream to each subscriber. I guess that is not something you would like.

If you switch to routed sessions you will only have one stream to the servers of TokBox and this server replicates to all subscribers and this server is not limited to the amount of subscribers.

Comment: +1 no software limit is in place on OpenTok, but you should definitely test your app on a few different devices to ensure overall app performance is acceptable for you.